# how to fix " Error loading stopwords" in pycharm

Tags: python, ssl, nltk

I am using Pycharm and when I run the below code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

I get this error msg?

```
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution, I share it here, I hope you find it helpful:

```
import ssl
try:
     _create_unverified_https_context =     ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
     pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain what's happening here?